# Firebase Auth. - Wordpress & R/Shiny

Tags: r, wordpress, firebase, shiny

I have a wordpress website and I'm using Firebase for auth. Also I have a R/Shiny app(I'm using same Firebase project for auth. in app (https://github.com/JohnCoene/firebase)).

I hosted that app with docker a container in app.fly.io.

When users login, they see Application button in my website. If users click on the button it's redirect users to app.mysite.com.

My problem is, users login in mysite then they click on Application button then they have to login one more time. I want to user login once.

How can I solve it? Any idea?

Comment: There is a similar concept. Please have a look at this one. 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hIBb_teDxcY